# Mongo error on I control hotfix

Tags: mongodb, windows-server-2008-r2

I have tried to start mongod.exe from my 2008 R2 server and im getting this error:

```
I CONTROL Hotfix kb2731284 or a later update is not installed, will zero-out files.
```

I didnt find any update or what is I CONTROL, someone have encounter with the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: This link [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8480) might help.

Comment: Hey,  i have download the update but still the error code remains.  any other ideas?

Comment: Have you restarted the server since performing the update?

Comment: of course. I think that the update require restarting after finishing.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with Windows 7 64 bit machine  with mongod version to be 3.2.7

Comment: I downloaded the update but seems the update is not applicable to my system. But still having this warning in log file

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Well, I just faced the same issue. I installed the fix, but saw nothing but same error. So that's how I got over it: just create a folder structure in your C catalog like this one:    C:\data\db. So it worked for me perfectly. I use Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the location of this folder structure? I would like it to point to another location if possible.

Comment: mongod --dbpath c:\my\new\path

Comment: Can you specify the link for the fix

Comment: Even this fix(creating folder in C: drive) worked in Win7 32-bit also; as E:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongod  --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath
c:\data\db

Answer (score 6):

I had to run the command in following format & it worked for me:

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data
```

Ref: [Original documentation link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#set-up-the-mongodb-environment)

Comment: This answer eliminated the hotfix error message for me.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was that I had a space in my data path: `E:\Program Files\MongoDB\Data\`

I ran `dir /x` within `E:\` to get the short path for `Program Files` and used the short path instead: `mongod.exe --dbpath E:\PROGRA~1\MongoDB\Data\`

It worked. Shocking that spaces in paths are still an issue!

Answer (score 3):

This known issue is in Windows 7. In Windows 8 this problem haven't appeared yet.

Firstly I would recommend to change your mongo installation path to path with folders names without gaps. For example, default mongo installation path is C:\program files\bla-bla... to avoid a wasting of time for looking for solutions of this issue, change your path to C:\mongo.. and make sure that you haven't names with gaps in your path.

After that install this [hot-fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2731284).

Another thing I suggest you to do: Create folder data\db in disc C.

You could also change your mongo work path each time you use mongo shell, but it's overwork by my modest opinion.
I've done these steps and my mongo has started to work.

Comment: The hotfix page loads, but the download link on that page no longer works (Sorry, the page you requested is not available.)

Answer (score 3):

The above error comes when `mongodb` not found the directory like "`C:\data\db`" which is by default when you install `mongodb` on your machine.
So just go to c drive create a directory like "data\db" and now run the command "mongodb.exe".

If you want to relocate the database location to any other drive say D drive in that case create a directory like "`D:\mongodb\data`" and run the command like "`mongodb.exe --dbpath d:\mongodb\data`".

Answer (score 3):

I got the similar error

```
I CONTROL Hotfix kb2731284 or a later update is installed, will zero-out files.
```

Notice the message says `later update is installed` not `later update is not installed` in my case. But It was not starting the server.

Creating a different folder structure for the db `Drive\<mongo-db-folder>\<yourdb>`and providing it with `--dbpath` flag while running the mongod worked for me. The short name for Program Files `PROGRA~1` didn't work for me. Maybe this has something to do with the rights managment.

Answer (score 2):

Getting started on mongodb was not that difficult. Well I have been facing similar error on mongodb to start. 
I have getting error

---

### Services

### Windows could not start the MongoDB on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 100.

### OK

very simple way to overcome.

Solution is the Mongodb service has not been started

to do so. Open CMD in admin mode and type NET START "Mongodb" > This will start the service.

Inspite of this if services is not getting started or mongo.exe is not starting. It is coz your mongodb has locked the file. Mongodb is shared file system and it gets locked. You need to for mongo.lock file in your created dir. Delete the file and start the service. You should be able to start now.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

By just creating a folder structure like below in my **"C:\"** drive , i resolved the issue :=>

> **c:\data\db**

[image]

Sometime it works without creating the above mentioned folder structure, i.e. MONGODB itself creates the same (as it worked for me in Windows 8 laptop) but sometimes it needs to be explicitly done (as i need to for my windows 7 installed desktop)

Also you can browse through the [complete installation and connection process](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) for MONGODB.

Answer (score 1):

Similiar to above, but I had a typo in my mongodb.cfg file which meant that Mongo couldn't find the data directory on startup. Fixed the typo and Mongo starts. Given the previous response I suspect that the failure to start is more of an issue over finding the data directory than the Hotfix message

Answer (score 1):

If you had got the below error message::

2015-05-29T05:05:54.207+0530 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not
installed, will zero-out data files
2015-05-29T05:05:54.219+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndLis
en: 29 Data directory D:\data\db\ not found., terminating
2015-05-29T05:05:54.219+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

then just create a directory "D:\data\db\""

then restart the mongod

it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

you need to have mongod.exe running in one cmd window. then use another cmd window, write mongo and hit enter

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the C:\Data\Db directory if you don't specify an existing directory when you run mongod.exe.
This directory is the default one.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

You can do fix [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating by following given two steps.

1. You can create the D:\data\db\ directory and restart the MongoDB server.
2. You can create the data folder as per your choice and run the server with the path of your data folder and restart the MongoDB server

i.e.  D:\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongod.exe  --dbpath  D:\MongoDB\Server\data​

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted `mongod.lock` in my db directory, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

1 : Download and install the fix from here :
http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Windows%207/Windows%20Server2008%20R2%20SP1/sp2/Fix405791/7600/free/451413_intl_x64_zip.exe
them reboot windows

2 : this you should make a folder called "data" and within it another one called "db"

c:/data/db ;

I would start with the second step , it's most likely to solve The problem .

Answer (score 0):

**As for what "I CONTROL" means**, the "I" is for "Information" (we have W for warning and E for error) and CONTROL is the component writing that log/message (we have also NETWORK, WRITE, QUERY and COMMAND components).

So you could get also `I COMMAND ...`, `I QUERY ...`, `I WRITE ...` :)

Answer (score -1):

Well, that is a common problem when you shut down your machine and mongodb server is running, it is pretty clear that MongoDb has created a lock in your db folder.

**Just go to c:\data\db and remove MONGOD.LOCK**

Run Mongo and it will work again.