# Not able to use mongo shell in intellij

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea, mongo-shell

i am able to connect to mongo db from intellij. Mongo explorer is working fine.

but after connecting when i try to open up Mongo Shell on any of the db it is not able to connect.

the error is coming on intellij I am running on Windows 7
throwing following error

```
2015-10-12T15:08:24.062-0700 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is installed, no need to zero-out data files
Invalid command: localhost:27017/students
Options:

General options:
  -h [ --help ]               show this usage information
  --version                   show version information
  -f [ --config ] arg         configuration file specifying additional options
  -v [ --verbose ] [=arg(=v)] be more verbose (include multiple times for more 
                              verbosity e.g. -vvvvv)
  --quiet                     quieter output
  --port arg                  specify port number - 27017 by default
  --bind_ip arg               comma separated list of ip addresses to listen on
                              - all local ips by default
  --ipv6                      enable IPv6 support (disabled by default)
  --maxConns arg              max number of simultaneous connections - 1000000 
                              by default
  --logpath arg               log file to send write to instead of stdout - has
                              to be a file, not directory
  --logappend                 append to logpath instead of over-writing
  --logRotate arg             set the log rotation behavior (rename|reopen)
  --timeStampFormat arg       Desired format for timestamps in log messages. 
                              One of ctime, iso8601-utc or iso8601-local
  --pidfilepath arg           full path to pidfile (if not set, no pidfile is 
                              created)
  --keyFile arg               private key for cluster authentication
  --setParameter arg          Set a configurable parameter
  --httpinterface             enable http interface
  --clusterAuthMode arg       Authentication mode used for cluster 
                              authentication. Alternatives are 
                              (keyFile|sendKeyFile|sendX509|x509)
  --auth                      run with security
  --noauth                    run without security
  --jsonp                     allow JSONP access via http (has security 
                              implications)
  --rest                      turn on simple rest api
  --slowms arg (=100)         value of slow for profile and console log
  --profile arg               0=off 1=slow, 2=all
  --cpu                       periodically show cpu and iowait utilization
  --sysinfo                   print some diagnostic system information
  --noIndexBuildRetry         don't retry any index builds that were 
                              interrupted by shutdown
  --noscripting               disable scripting engine
  --notablescan               do not allow table scans

Windows Service Control Manager options:
  --install                install Windows service
  --remove                 remove Windows service
  --reinstall              reinstall Windows service (equivalent to --remove 
                           followed by --install)
  --serviceName arg        Windows service name
  --serviceDisplayName arg Windows service display name
  --serviceDescription arg Windows service description
  --serviceUser arg        account for service execution
  --servicePassword arg    password used to authenticate serviceUser

Replication options:
  --oplogSize arg       size to use (in MB) for replication op log. default is 
                        5% of disk space (i.e. large is good)

Master/slave options (old; use replica sets instead):
  --master              master mode
  --slave               slave mode
  --source arg          when slave: specify master as <server:port>
  --only arg            when slave: specify a single database to replicate
  --slavedelay arg      specify delay (in seconds) to be used when applying 
                        master ops to slave
  --autoresync          automatically resync if slave data is stale

Replica set options:
  --replSet arg           arg is <setname>[/<optionalseedhostlist>]
  --replIndexPrefetch arg specify index prefetching behavior (if secondary) 
                          [none|_id_only|all]

Sharding options:
  --configsvr           declare this is a config db of a cluster; default port 
                        27019; default dir /data/configdb
  --shardsvr            declare this is a shard db of a cluster; default port 
                        27018

SSL options:
  --sslOnNormalPorts                    use ssl on configured ports
  --sslMode arg                         set the SSL operation mode 
                                        (disabled|allowSSL|preferSSL|requireSSL
                                        )
  --sslPEMKeyFile arg                   PEM file for ssl
  --sslPEMKeyPassword arg               PEM file password
  --sslClusterFile arg                  Key file for internal SSL 
                                        authentication
  --sslClusterPassword arg              Internal authentication key file 
                                        password
  --sslCAFile arg                       Certificate Authority file for SSL
  --sslCRLFile arg                      Certificate Revocation List file for 
                                        SSL
  --sslWeakCertificateValidation        allow client to connect without 
                                        presenting a certificate
  --sslAllowConnectionsWithoutCertificates 
                                        allow client to connect without 
                                        presenting a certificate
  --sslAllowInvalidHostnames            Allow server certificates to provide 
                                        non-matching hostnames
  --sslAllowInvalidCertificates         allow connections to servers with 
                                        invalid certificates
  --sslFIPSMode                         activate FIPS 140-2 mode at startup

Storage options:
  --storageEngine arg (=mmapv1) what storage engine to use
  --dbpath arg                  directory for datafiles - defaults to \data\db\
                                which is C:\data\db\ based on the current 
                                working drive
  --directoryperdb              each database will be stored in a separate 
                                directory
  --noprealloc                  disable data file preallocation - will often 
                                hurt performance
  --nssize arg (=16)            .ns file size (in MB) for new databases
  --quota                       limits each database to a certain number of 
                                files (8 default)
  --quotaFiles arg              number of files allowed per db, implies --quota
  --smallfiles                  use a smaller default file size
  --syncdelay arg (=60)         seconds between disk syncs (0=never, but not 
                                recommended)
  --upgrade                     upgrade db if needed
  --repair                      run repair on all dbs
  --repairpath arg              root directory for repair files - defaults to 
                                dbpath
  --journal                     enable journaling
  --nojournal                   disable journaling (journaling is on by default
                                for 64 bit)
  --journalOptions arg          journal diagnostic options
  --journalCommitInterval arg   how often to group/batch commit (ms)

WiredTiger options:
  --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB arg           maximum amount of memory to allocate 
                                        for cache; defaults to 1/2 of physical 
                                        RAM
  --wiredTigerStatisticsLogDelaySecs arg (=0)
                                        seconds to wait between each write to a
                                        statistics file in the dbpath; 0 means 
                                        do not log statistics
  --wiredTigerJournalCompressor arg (=snappy)
                                        use a compressor for log records 
                                        [none|snappy|zlib]
  --wiredTigerDirectoryForIndexes       Put indexes and data in different 
                                        directories
  --wiredTigerCollectionBlockCompressor arg (=snappy)
                                        block compression algorithm for 
                                        collection data [none|snappy|zlib]
  --wiredTigerIndexPrefixCompression arg (=1)
                                        use prefix compression on row-store 
                                        leaf pages


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I did some debugging in my answer and then realized you might not be using a mac - see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316482/mongo-error-on-i-control-hotfix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an open issue with the plugin it self. Please follow at this location for the updates:

[https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea/issues/107#issuecomment-155239346]

Comment: Now the plugin update is available and this issue is resolved after installing the update on intellij. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On Mac 10.10.5, using IntelliJ 14.1.5 with a fresh install of Mongo plugin (Mongo explorer), set the Path to Mongo Executable to /usr/local/bin/mongo (my homebrew install) in Mongo Explorer settings, added a server (name: local - localhost:27017), clicked Test Connection which responded OK, clicked Apply and OK, then double clicked the 'local' item in Mongo explorer and all worked well.

On mac 10.11 I had to do a bit of fixing for homebrew - install the new XCode, launch it and agree to terms, `sudo xcodebuild -license`, fix perms in `/usr/local` with `sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`. After a brew update, mongo was still screwed up so I uninstalled and reinstalled and mongodb `brew install mongodb`, started mongo from the command line with success. After that, I re-installed the IntelliJ Mongo plugin and followed instructions above and all worked fine.

Does this reveal your underlying problem? Does it hint at more details you can share to help identify your problem?

Comment: i am getting this issue on Windows 7 and still not able to resolve it. till test connection it is working fine but when i try to open a shell to write some query it is giving the above error.

Comment: i have upgraded to intellij idea 15 but still not able to mongo shell in intellij. getting the different error though. NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/execution/runners/ConsoleExecuteActionHandler

Answer (score 0):

I was able to circumvent the following config.

CMD Command
**mongod.exe --config="C:....\MongoDB\mongo.config" --logappend**

Ensure that **data\db folder** is created

Create Configuration File with contents:
**dbpath=C:...\MongoDB\data
logpath=C:...\MongoDB\log\mongodb.log**

Answer (score 0):

If you select the wrong path to Mongo Shell you will be faced the same issue. 
it must be `%MONGO_DIR%\bin\mongo.exe`, not  `%MONGO_DIR%\bin\mongod.exe`[image: mongo path]